# How can I extract non repeated rows

Tags: r

For example

```
Ride_id   end_staion_name Other_columns
1         A     
2         B
3         A
4         C
5         A
6         A 
7         D
8         D
9         E
10        A
```

Desired result

```
all_end_station_names      Count (Optional)
A                            5
B                            1
C                            1
D                            2
E                            1
```

Comment: With `dplyr`:  `count(your_data, end_station_name)`.

Comment: `table(dat$end_station_name)`

Comment: `my_data[!duplicated(my_data$end_station_name), ]` will remove the rows with duplicated stations

Answer (score 0):

Using `table` and coerce.

```
with(dat, as.data.frame.table(table(end_staion_name)))
#   end_staion_name Freq
# 1               A    5
# 2               B    1
# 3               C    1
# 4               D    2
# 5               E    1
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Ride_id = 1:10, end_staion_name = c("A", "B", 
"A", "C", "A", "A", "D", "D", "E", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```